# Azure Notification hub Free Tier - are 1 million pushes per month?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub, price

Azure Notification hub free tier has 1million pushes per subscription.
My question is are 1 million pushes per month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`pricing`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/),

**`Free`** - get up to 1 million pushes per subscription a month.

**`Basic`** - get 10 million pushes per subscription a month as a baseline, with quota growth options.

**`Standard`** - get 10 million pushes per subscription a month as a baseline, with quota increase options, plus rich telemetry capabilties

Comment: Mark if the answer helped

Answer (score 0):

All of the prices listed on this page are monthly: [Notification Hub Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/)

So as of the time of writing you are correct, the 1 million pushes are evaluated monthly by subscription.

Comment: what is different from the answer i posted?